# Unity3D GUI.Box, Scaling its text

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In Unity3D I have this GUI Box that I scaled to the screen size. But the problem is that its text is not scaled correctly.  The text has the same font size for any screen resolution.  How can I set up the text's height and width when I display it? Screen Resolution is 1920 x 1080. Appreciate the help!

[image: The Screen Resolution is 1920 x 1080 1]

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - Screen.width / 6 / 2, Screen.height - Screen.height / 8, Screen.width / 6, Screen.height / 8), ("View [E]"));
```

Comment: Stop using OnGui and start using [the new UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui)

Comment: I can't really find the equivalent of OnGUI() in the new UI.  What do I use for creating a box with scaled text then? Could you give me a more specific approach?

Comment: GameObject Menu -> UI -> Panel

Comment: Yes I know about panels, but I want to make one via C# script.  Also, I don't want to make another canvas.  I want something like when a player moves to an object, a panel appears, sort of like what is shown in the picture above.

Comment: The new UI uses gameobjects with attached components. You want to create a panel at runtime? Use a prefab.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you can make a new GUIStyle with the preferences you want.

```
GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle(); 
myStyle.fontSize = 20;
GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - Screen.width / 6 / 2, Screen.height - Screen.height / 8, Screen.width / 6, Screen.height / 8), "Hello", myStyle);
```

Link about more style are here: [GUIStyles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html)